# ECDH entre C# e javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, criptografia

Eu to criando uma web API e preciso implementar o ECDH pra uma criptografia ponta a ponta. Do lado do servidor tenho uma aplicação C# e do lado do cliente uma aplicação javascript.

Eu consigo trocar as chaves, gerar as chaves privadas e criptografar uma mensagem, mas não consigo descriptografá-la.

Eu acho que o problema está na troca de chaves públicas. No javascript as chaves começam com um byte "4" e no .NET as chaves começam com 8 bytes identificando o tipo e tamanho da chave, para conseguir importar as chaves eu preciso modificar esses bytes iniciais (Informação que encontrei [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24255090/10297094)). Talvez isso cause alguma inconsistência.

Do lado do cliente estou usando a Web Cryptography API para realizar o ECDH. E estou implementando conforme abaixo.

Gerando as chaves

```
await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
        {
            name: "ECDH",
            namedCurve: "P-256",
        },
        false,
        ["deriveKey", "deriveBits"]
    );
```

Exportando as chaves públicas:

```
await window.crypto.subtle.exportKey(
        "raw",
        publicKey
    );
```

Importando as chaves públicas externas

```
await window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
        "raw",
        {
            name: "ECDH",
            namedCurve: "P-256",
        },
        false,
        ["deriveKey", "deriveBits"]
    )
```

E finalmente gerando as chaves privadas

```
await window.crypto.subtle.deriveKey(
        {
            name: "ECDH",
            namedCurve: "P-256",
            public: publicKey,
        },
        privateKey,
        {
            name: "AES-CBC",
            length: 256,
        },
        false,
        ["encrypt", "decrypt"]
    )
```

Do lado do servidor eu estou fazendo os mesmos passos da seguinte forma.
Gerando chave pública

```
private static ECDiffieHellmanCng ecdh = new ECDiffieHellmanCng(256);

public static void GeneratePublicKey()
{
    ecdh.KeyDerivationFunction = ECDiffieHellmanKeyDerivationFunction.Hash;
    ecdh.HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.Sha256;
    publicKey = ecdh.PublicKey.ToByteArray();
}
```

Exportando chave pública. Note que estou mudando os primeiros bytes

```
public static byte[] GetPublicKey()
    {
        var auxKey = publicKey.Skip(7).ToArray();
        auxKey[0] = 4;

        return auxKey;
    }
```

Importando a chave pública e gerando a chave privada. Note que estou mudando os primeiros bytes

```
public static void GerarChavePrivada(byte[] bobPublicKey)
{
    byte[] aux = new byte[bobPublicKey.Length + 7];

    aux[0] = 0x45;
    aux[1] = 0x43;
    aux[2] = 0x4B;
    aux[3] = 0x31;
    aux[4] = 0x20;
    aux[5] = 0x00;
    aux[6] = 0x00;
    aux[7] = 0x00;

    for (int i = 1; i < bobPublicKey.Length; i++)
    {
        aux[7 + i] = bobPublicKey[i];
    }

    var importedKey = CngKey.Import(aux, CngKeyBlobFormat.EccPublicBlob);
    privateKey = ecdh.DeriveKeyMaterial(importedKey);
}
```

Eu acredito que o problema está nessas chaves. De qualquer forma estou criptografando e descriptografando da seguinte forma:

Javascript

```
async function encrypt2(iv, key, data){
    var mensagemCriptografada;

    await window.crypto.subtle.encrypt(
        {
            name: "AES-CBC",
            iv: iv,
        },
        key,
        str2ab(data) //Data é uma string e estou convertendo em base64 usando o método str2ab.
    )

    .then(function(encrypted){
        mensagemCriptografada = encrypted;
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.error(err);
    });

    return mensagemCriptografada;
}

function str2ab (str) {
    var array = new Uint8Array(str.length);     
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        array[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return array.buffer
}
```

C#

```
string decMessage = "";

        using (Aes aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            aes.Key = privateKey;
            aes.IV = iv; //O IV é o mesmo usado pelo javascript
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

            var dec = aes.CreateDecryptor(privateKey, iv);

            var plain = dec.TransformFinalBlock(message, 0, message.Length);

            //Tentei todos os Encodings possíveis.
            decMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plain); 
        }

        return decMessage;
```

Eu realmente não tenho ideia de como resolver esse problema.